# I'm turning the Discord bot into Python, and I keep getting errors in my command Help me

Tags: python, discord.py

Currently, I finished typing the discord bot command with Python, but I got an error as if the word print is underlined. I don't know how to solve it. It doesn't come out after searching the Internet several times,and there's no answer to other people's requests. I'm in a hurry. Please explain!
[image]

Comment: In python, indentation is very important, When you define a function, do it like this,
```def func():
         print('whatever')
```

Comment: The content of a python method is defined by indentation of the lines that are part of the method. You need to add spaces in front of print and each line that is part of the on_ready method

Comment: There's no answer if you search "Expected indent block"? Also [Do not add "in a hurry" or similar phrases to your posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 3):

As the error message indicate, you have an indentation error. IndentationError when indentation is not correct, it is raised.

```py
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

token = "Your Token"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user.name)
    print('Bot start!')
    game = discord.Game('Bot name')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game)

client.run(token)
```

And I recommend if you have question about discord py, don't show your bot token in your code.